# if condition for a selected month and the current month comparison

Tags: c#, mysql, sharepoint

I need to apply a condition for field a my project where, I need compare the current month's last date with the month selected in the field and if they current months last date is more than 1 month in accordance to the selected month then an error be displayed.
can anyone please help me???

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstOfThisMonth = now.AddDays(-now.Days+1);
DateTime firstOfNextMonth = firstOfThisMonth.AddMonths(1);
DateTime endOfThisMonth = firstOfNextMonth.AddDays(-1);
```

Now you can compare `endOfThisMonth` with selected month.